# Match regex string, but also return optional leading whitespace

Tags: python, regex

Imagine I have a multiline string, which contains tokens of the format `{{ string_a }}`, and can be placed either on their own line with possible leading whitespace, or on the same line as some other markup.

```
a: {{ string_a }}

b:
  {{ string_b }}
```

I am trying to write a regex which will match the contents of these tokens and do a replacement, but I would also like to run some conditional logic based on whether or not they exist on their own line.

My original regex is pretty basic: `\{\{\s*([A-Za-z_]+)\s*\}\}` and it does a fine job of matching the tokens. However, when I try and match the leading whitespace and put that into a capturing group, it only matches those with whitespace, when really I want all the tokens regardless:

```
(^\s*)\{\{\s*([A-Za-z_]+)\s*\}\}
```

[image: Broken regex]

I imagine that the solution is to use some sort of lookahead/lookbehind, but whichever I try, it seems to break. Not sure if this is because of the `^` or the `*` in that first group, but it doesn't like it either way.

So, what I'm trying to get as my capture list is the following:

- The full token `{{ string_a }}`
- The inner string `string_a`
- Whitespace or not `\s\s\s`, to do boolean conditional logic on

Comment: Python tag because it's pythonic regex syntax, but could remove if it seems unnecessary

Comment: That's fine, actually we basically *require* all [tag:regex] questions to also specify the language or platform, ideally with a suitable tag.

Comment: if its an optional space at the start of the string could you not start your regex with `(\s)?`

Comment: This looks suspiciously like you are attempting to parse YAML or some other structured format with regular expressions. Don't do that. Google for cthulhu zalgo html.

Comment: I'm not parsing YAML. I'm doing token replacement on a relatively weird and esoteric chatbot language, and unfortunately I'm tasked with transpiling in Python rather than using the original. Horses for courses. (weird and esoteric in the way it's basically unlike any other language, save perhaps some smalltalk influence, perhaps). My example is just the MCVE version of it too, for the sake of focussing on the regex question

Comment: And yes, I've been on SO for over 6 years, I've seen the cthulhu post ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `(^\s*)?\{\{\s*([A-Za-z_]+)\s*\}\}`. The only difference is a single `?`.

[image]

The problem with `(^\s*)` is that the `^` is not optional.

Comment: Ah that's so very simple and should've been obvious! Pre-9am pre-coffee Monday brain to blame. Was trying to overcomplicate with lookbehinds. Thanks

Comment: By the way, escaping `{` and `}` is only necessary when it would be ambiguous to the parser. `(^\s*)?{{\s*([A-Za-z_]+)\s*}}` works just as well.

Comment: Yeah I just do it as a matter of habit really. Quick extra question, it seems my `re.finditer` is not actually matching the whitespace group. Always comes out as `None`. Is there a flag I'm missing? Cheers

Comment: `m` flag for all I can tell.

Comment: D'oh. Appreciate it